# CATCH and throw in custom exception

Tags: raku

Should 'CATCH' be called strictly after 'throw'?

**Example 1:**

```
say 'Hello World!';

class E is Exception { method message() { "Just stop already!" } }

CATCH {
    when E {
            .resume;
    }
}

E.new.throw;
```

**Error:**

> Cannot find method 'sink': no method cache and no .^find_method   in
>   block  at /tmp/739536251/main.pl6 line 11

**Example 2:**

```
say 'Hello World!';

class E is Exception { method message() { "Just stop already!" } }

E.new.throw;

CATCH {
    when E {
            .resume;
    }
}
```

No error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [an already filed `.resume` bug](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2667).

---

The error message isn't the most awesome P6 has ever produced but it isn't technically [LTA](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#LTA) because it is descriptive and related to the error (caused by the bug).

---

> CATCH and throw in custom exception

I think it's just a `.resume` bug rather than being about custom exceptions.

> Should 'CATCH' be called strictly after 'throw'?

No, that's not the issue. (That said, putting it after the `.throw` just so happens to avoid this bug; I'll return to that later.)

---

In the code that goes boom, you throw an exception, then [`.resume`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Exception#method_resume) in response to it. Per the doc `.resume`:

> Resumes control flow where `.throw` left it

Which in this case means where the arrow points:

```
E.new.throw ;
```

Now, consider this program:

```
42;
```

If you run that program you'll see:

```
Useless use of constant integer 42 in sink context (line 1)
```

That's because Raku applies ["sink context"](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts#Sink) rules when deciding what to do at the end of a statement. Applying sink context entails calling `.sink` on the value produced by the statement. And for `42` the `.sink` method generates the "useless" warning.

But what's the value of a `.resume`d thrown exception?

```
class E is Exception {}
CATCH { when E { .resume } }
say E.new.throw.^name; # BOOTException
E.new.throw.sink;      # Cannot find method 'sink':
                       # no method cache and no .^find_method
```

It turns out it's a `BOOTException` object which isn't a high level Raku object but instead a low level VM object, one that doesn't have a `.sink` method (and also stymies P6's fallback methods for finding a method, hence the "I tried everything" error message).

---

So why does putting the `CATCH` block *after* the throw make a difference?

It seems the bug only occurs if the throw statement is the *last* statement. This works fine, just displaying `42`:

```
class E is Exception {}
CATCH { when E { .resume } }
E.new.throw;
say 42;
```

As you presumably know, Raku treats the last statement of a block specially. Perhaps this bug is related to that.

Answer (score 4):

`CATCH` must be in same block.

Problem in the first example is that no `E` but another exceptions is thrown. Try

```
class E is Exception { method message() { "Just stop already!" } };

CATCH {
    when E {
        .resume;
    }
    default { say .perl }
}

E.new.throw;
```

you could change `when` block

```
class E is Exception { method message() { "Just stop already!" } };

CATCH {
    when E {
        say .message;
    }
}

E.new.throw;
```

or definition of the class `E`, e.g.

```
class E is Exception { 
    has $.resume; 
    method message() { "Just stop already!" } 
};

CATCH {
    when E {
        say .resume;
    }
}

E.new(resume => 'stop here').throw;
```

Comment: ok,  The information ("there is no method (attribute) resume." ) was misleading. I've removed it from the answer.