# Actually CATCHing exceptions without creating GOTO

Tags: exception, raku, goto, rakudo

Looking over my Raku code, I've realized that I pretty much never use `CATCH` blocks to actually catch/handle error.  Instead, I handle errors with `try` blocks and testing for undefined values; the only thing I use `CATCH` blocks for is to log errors differently. I don't seem to be alone in this habit – looking at the `CATCH` blocks in the [Raku docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/exceptions), pretty much none of them handle the error in any sense beyond printing a message.  (The same is true of most of the `CATCH` blocks in Rakudo.).

Nevertheless, I'd like to better understand how to use `CATCH` blocks.  Let me work through a few example functions, all of which are based on the following basic idea:

```
sub might-die($n) { $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! die 418 }
```

Now, as I've said, I'd normally use this function with something like

```
say try { might-die(3) } // 'default';
```

But I'd like to avoid that here and use `CATCH` blocks inside the function.  My first instinct is to write

```
sub might-die1($n) {
    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! die 418
    CATCH { default { 'default' }}
}
```

But this not only doesn't work, it also (very helpfully!) doesn't even compile.  Apparently, the `CATCH` block is *not* removed from the control flow (as I would have thought).  Thus, that block, rather than the ternary expression, is the last statement in the function.  Ok, fair enough.  How about this:

```
    sub might-die2($n) {
ln1:    CATCH { default { 'default' }}
ln2:    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! die 418
    }
```

(those line numbers are [`Lables`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Label).  Yes, it's valid Raku and, yes, they're useless here.  But SO doesn't give line numbers, and I wanted some.)

This at least compiles, but it doesn't do what I mean.

```
say might-die2(3);  # OUTPUT: «Nil»
```

To DWIM, I can change this to

```
    sub might-die3($n) {
ln1:    CATCH { default { return 'default' }}
ln2:    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! die 418
    }
say might-die3(3);  # OUTPUT: «'default'»
```

What these two reveal is that the result of the `CATCH` block is *not*, as I'd hopped, being inserted into control flow where the exception occurred.  Instead, the exception is causing control flow to jump to the `CATCH` block for the enclosing scope.  It's as though we'd written (in an alternate universe where Raku has a `GOTO` operator [EDIT: or maybe not *that* alternate of a universe, since we apparently have [a NYI `goto` method](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core.c/Label.pm6#L22).  Learn something new every day…]

```
    sub might-die4($n) {
ln0:    GOTO ln2;
ln1:    return 'default';
ln2:    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! GOTO ln1;
    }
```

I realize that some critics of exceptions [say](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) that they can reduce to `GOTO` statements, but this seems to be carrying things a bit far.

I could (mostly) avoid emulating `GOTO` with the `.resume` method, but I can't do it the way I'd like to.  Specifically, I can't write:

```
    sub might-die5($n) {
ln1:    CATCH { default { .resume('default') }}
ln2:    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! die 418
    }
```

Because `.resume` doesn't take an argument. I *can* write

```
    sub might-die6($n) {
ln1:    CATCH { default { .resume }}
ln2:    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! do { die 418; 'default' }
    }
say might-die6 3;  # OUTPUT: «'default'»
```

This works, at least in this particular example.  But I can't help feeling that it's more of a hack than an actual solution and that it wouldn't generalize well.  Indeed, I can't help feeling that I'm missing some larger insight behind error handling in Raku that would make all of this fit together better.  (Maybe because I've spent too much time programming in languages that handle errors without exceptions?)  I would appreciate any insight into how to write the above code in idiomatic Raku.  Is one of the approaches above basically correct?  Is there a different approach I haven't considered?  And is there a larger insight about error handling that I'm missing in all of this?

Comment: See also [Returning values from exception handlers in Perl 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51644197/2173773), [When would I want to resume a Perl 6 exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43304911/2173773), and [CATCH and throw in custom exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58041372/2173773)

Comment: Thanks, @HåkonHægland.  I'd seen the first and third of those, but had missed the second, and it adds a valuable perspective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## "Larger insight about error handling"

> Is one of the approaches [in my question] basically correct?

Yes. In the general case, use features like `try` and `if`, not `CATCH`.

> Is there a different approach I haven't considered?

Here's a brand new one: [`catch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51695109/1077672). I invented the first version of it a few weeks ago, and now your question has prompted me to reimagine it. I'm pretty happy with how it's now settled; I'd appreciate readers' feedback about it.

> is there a larger insight about error handling that I'm missing in all of this?

I'll discuss some of my thoughts at the end of this answer.

But let's now go through your points in the order you wrote them.

## KISS

> I pretty much never use `CATCH` blocks to actually catch/handle error.

Me neither.

> Instead, I handle errors with `try` blocks and testing for undefined values

That's more like it.

## Logging errors with a catchall `CATCH`

> the only thing I use `CATCH` blocks for is to log errors differently.

Right. A judiciously located catch*all*. This is a use case for which I'd say `CATCH` *is* a good fit.

## The doc

> looking at the `CATCH` blocks in the [Raku docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/exceptions), pretty much none of them handle the error in any sense beyond printing a message.

If the doc is misleading about:

- The limits of the capabilities and applicability of `CATCH` / `CONTROL` blocks; and/or
- The alternatives; and/or
- What's idiomatic (which imo is *not* use of `CATCH` for code where `try` is more appropriate (and now my new `catch` function too?)).

then that would be unfortunate.

## `CATCH` blocks in the Rakudo compiler source

> (The same is true of most of the `CATCH` blocks in Rakudo.).

At a guess those will be judiciously placed catchalls. Placing one just before the callstack runs out, to specify default exception handling (as either a warning plus `.resume`, or a `die` or similar), seems reasonable to me. Is that what they all are?

## Why are [phasers](https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers) statements?

```
sub might-die1($n) {
    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! die 418
    CATCH { default { 'default' }}
}
```

> this not only doesn't work, it also (very helpfully!) doesn't even compile.

.oO ( Well that's because you forgot a semi-colon at the end of the first statement )

> (I would have thought ... the `CATCH` block [would have been] removed from the control flow)

Join the club. Others have expressed related sentiments in filed bugs, and SO Q's and A's. I used to think the current situation was wrong in the same way you express. I think I could now easily be persuaded by either side of the argument -- but jnthn's view would be decisive for me.

---

Quoting the doc:

> A phaser block is *just a trait* of the closure containing it, and is automatically called at the appropriate moment.

That suggests that a phaser is *not* a statement, at least not in an ordinary sense and would, one might presume, be removed from ordinary control flow.

But returning to the doc:

> Phasers [may] have a runtime value, and if evaluated [in a] surrounding expression, they simply save their result for use in the expression ... when the rest of the expression is evaluated.

That suggests that they *can* have a *value* in an *ordinary* control flow sense.

---

Perhaps the rationale for *not* removing phasers from holding their place in ordinary control flow, and instead evaluating to `Nil` if they don't otherwise return a value, is something like:

- Phasers like `INIT` *do* return values. The compiler could insist that one assigns their result to a variable and then explicitly returns that variable. But that would be very un Raku-ish.
- Raku philosophy is that, in general, the dev tells the compiler what to do or not do, not the other way around. A phaser is a statement. If you put a statement at the end, then you want it to be the value returned by its enclosing block. (Even if it's `Nil`.)

---

Still, overall, I'm with you in the following sense:

- It seems natural to think that ordinary control flow does not include phasers that do not return a value. Why should it?
- It seems IWBNI the compiler at least *warned* if it saw a non-value-returning phaser used as the last statement of a block that contains other value-returning statements.

## Why don't `CATCH` blocks return/inject a value?

> Ok, fair enough.  How about this:

```
    sub might-die2($n) {
ln1:    CATCH { default { 'default' }}
ln2:    $n %% 2 ?? 'lives' !! die 418
    }

    say might-die2(3);  # OUTPUT: «Nil»
```

As discussed above, many phasers, including the exception handling ones, are statements that do not return values.

I think one could reasonably have expected that:

- `CATCH` phasers *would* return a value. But they don't. I vaguely recall jnthn already explaining why here on SO; I'll leave hunting that down as an exercise for readers. Or, conversely:
- The compiler would warn that a phaser that did not return a value was placed somewhere a returned value was probably intended.

---

> It's as though we'd written ... a `GOTO` operator

Raku(do) isn't just doing an unstructured jump.

(Otherwise `.resume` wouldn't work.)

> this seems to be carrying things a bit far

I agree, you are carrying things a bit too far. :P

## `.resume`

> Resumable exceptions certainly aren't something I've found myself reaching for in Raku. I don't think I've used them in "userspace" code at all yet.

(from [jnthn's answer to *When would I want to resume a Raku exception?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43333653/1077672).)

> `.resume` doesn't take an argument

Right. It just resumes execution at the statement after the one that led to an exception being thrown. `.resume` does not alter the result of the failed statement.

Even if a `CATCH` block tries to intervene, it won't be able to do so in a simple, self-contained fashion, by setting the value of a variable whose assignment has thrown an exception, and then `.resume`ing. cf [Should this Raku `CATCH` block be able to change variables in the lexical scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289842/should-this-perl-6-catch-block-be-able-to-change-variables-in-the-lexical-scope).

(I tried several `CATCH` related approaches before concluding that just using `try` was the way to go for the body of the `catch` function I linked at the start. If you haven't already looked at the `catch` code, I recommend you do.)

## Further tidbits about `CATCH` blocks

They're a bit fraught for a couple reasons. One is what seems to be deliberate limits of their intended capability and applicability. Another is bugs. Consider, for example:

- [My answer to SO *`CATCH` and throw in custom exception*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58044997/1077672)
- [Rakudo issue: *Missing return value from do when calling `.resume` and `CATCH` is the last statement in a block*](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2181)
- [Rakudo issue: *`return`-ing out of a block and LEAVE phaser (“identity”‽)*](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2380)

## Larger insight about error handling

> is there a larger insight about error handling that I'm missing in all of this?

Perhaps. I think you already know most of it well, but:

- **KISS #1** You've handled errors without exceptions in other PLs. It worked. You've done it in Raku. It works. Use exceptions only when you *need* or *want* to use them. For most code, you won't.
- **KISS #2** Ignoring some native type use cases, almost all results can be expressed as valid or not valid, without leading to the [semi-predicate problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semipredicate_problem), using simple combinations of the following Raku [Truth value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_value) that provide ergonomic ways to discern between non-error values and errors:

  - Conditionals: `if`, `while`, `try`, `//`, et al
  - Predicates: `.so`, `.defined`, `.DEFINITE`, et al
  - Values/types: `Nil`, `Failure`s, zero length composite data structures, `:D` vs `:U` type constraints, et al

Sticking with error exceptions, some points I think worth considering:

- One of the use cases for Raku error exceptions is to cover the same ground as exceptions in, say, Haskell. These are scenarios in which handling them as values isn't the right solution (or, in Raku, *might* not be).
- Other PLs support exceptions. One of Raku's superpowers is being able to interoperate with all other PLs. Ergo it supports exceptions if for no other reason than to enable correct interoperation.
- Raku includes the notion of a `Failure`, a delayed exception. The idea is you can get the best of both worlds. Handled with due care, a `Failure` is just an error value. Handled carelessly, it blows up like a regular exception.

More generally, all of Raku's features are designed to work together to provide convenient but high quality error handling that supports all of the following coding scenarios:

- Fast coding. Prototyping, exploratory code, one-offs, etc.
- Control of robustness. Gradually narrowing or broadening error handling.
- Diverse options. What errors should be signalled? When? By which code? What if consuming code wants to signal that producing code should be more strict? Or more relaxed? What if it's the other way around -- *producing* code wants to signal that *consuming* code should be more careful or can relax? What can be done if producing and consuming code have conflicting philosophies? What if producing code cannot be altered (eg it's a library, or written in another language)?
- Interoperation between languages / codebases. The only way that can work well is if Raku provides both high levels of control and diverse options.
- Convenient refactoring between these scenarios.

All of these factors, and more, underlie Raku's approach to error handling.

Comment: Thanks, very informative!  On &might-die1, I certainly did _not_ forget the semicolon :D  I left it off intentionally because, if `CATCH` were actually removed from the control flow then it wouldn't be necessary (I generally prefer to omit semicolons wherever I'm intending to use an implicit return, precisely so that the compiler will complain if I'm not returning).  In this particular case, I also tested with the semicolon; I thought that "sink context" error message would take longer to explain in the context of this question and was basically a distraction.

Comment: A few other points, in no order.  1) Thanks for the link to `trys`; it's interesting and inspired me to write up an answer to that question providing a different (though similar) approach.  2) the third link in your Masochism section points to the wrong issue; it should point to #2380.  3)  You present Raku as generally not using exceptions all that often.  I'll have to give this more thought, but I'm not sure I agree.  I would agree, I think … except for our type system – which is mostly enforced by exceptions thrown at runtime (discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63486574)

Comment: I've got an edit in the works addressing the following. Thx for fixes etc. "You present Raku as generally not using exceptions all that often." Then I did a poor job of explaining. Raku uses exceptions all over the shop. What I mean is that there's sugar sprinkled atop. Thus to return a value from a block we just write `return`, or just a final statement in a block, rather than laboriously write out an explicit enclosed `CONTROL` block. Similarly, we just use `try` instead of laboriously writing out `CATCH` blocks. There are... exceptions, when the sugar isn't adequate, but they're exceptions.

Comment: The edit I have in the works for this answer has been awaiting an edit I had in the works for the `trys` answer. I had thought about calling it `try-catch` when I first wrote it but decided I didn't like the length; didn't feel it quite captured what I was trying to pull off; and could too easily make someone think that code of the form `try-catch { ... }, { ... }` was such that the first block was a `try`, and the second was a `CATCH`. But I now feel I've nicely addressed those name problems, plus some others. If you revisit what was `trys` you'll find it's now `catch`. Feedback welcome!

Answer (score 5):

`CATCH` is a really old feature of the language.
It used to only exist [inside of a `try`](https://github.com/Raku/roast/commit/72c762d1adf8f3134bb00c78373d95ac78df555e#diff-4083adad9f6697ba84c05c5c42d2a49d323c6e962e49952d5af734c32423a9f6) block.
(Which is not very Rakuish.)

It is also a very rarely used part of Raku.
Which means that not a lot of people have come up with *“pain points”* of the feature.
So then very rarely has anyone done any work to make it more Rakuish.

Both of those combined make it so that `CATCH` is a rather featureless part of the language.
If you look at the test file for the feature, you will note that most of it was [written in 2009](https://github.com/Raku/roast/blame/beeb2cb31d67b970f756e1f1490b2f482bb34397/S04-exception-handlers/catch.t) when the test suite was still a part of the Pugs project.
(And most of the rest are tests for bugs that have been found over the years.)

---

There is a very good reason that few people have tried to add new behaviours to `CATCH`, there are plenty of other features that are much nicer to work with.

If you want to replace a result in the event of an exception

```raku
sub may-die () {
  if Bool.pick {
    return 'normal'
  } else {
    die
  }
}
```

```raku
my $result;
{
  CATCH { default { $result = 'replacement' }}
  $result = may-die();
}
```

It is much easier to just use `try` without `CATCH`, along with defined‑or `//` to get something that works very similarly.

```raku
my $result = try { may-die } // 'replacement';
```

It is even easier if you are dealing with soft failures instead of hard exceptions, because you can just use defined‑or by itself.

```raku
sub may-fail () {
  if Bool.pick {
    return 'normal'
  } else {
    fail
  }
}
```

```raku
my $result = may-fail() // 'replacement';
```

In fact the only way to use `CATCH` with a soft failure is to combine it with `try`

```raku
my $result;
try {
  CATCH { default { $result = 'replacement' }}
  $result = may-fail();
}
```

If your soft failure is the base of all failure objects `Nil`, you can either use `//` or `is default`

```raku
my $result = may-return-nil // 'replacement';
```

```raku
my $result is default<replacement> = may-return-nil;
```

But `Nil` won't just work with `CATCH` no matter how much you `try`.

---

Really the only time I would normally use `CATCH` is when I want to handle several different errors in different ways.

```raku
{
  CATCH {
    when X::Something { … }
    when X::This      { … }
    when X::That      { … }

    default           { … }
  }

  # some code that may throw X::This
  …
  # some code that may throw X::NotSpecified (default)
  …
  # some code that may throw X::Something
  …
  # some code that may throw X::This or X::That
  …

  # some code that may fail instead of throw
  # (sunk so that it will throw immediately)
  sink may-fail;
}
```

Or if I wanted to show how you could write this [terrible] Visual Basic line

```raku
On Error Resume Next
```

In Raku

```raku
CATCH { default { .resume } }
```

---

That of course doesn't really answer your question in the slightest.

You say that you expected `CATCH` to be removed from the control flow.
The whole point of `CATCH` is to insert itself into the exceptional control flow.

Actually that's not accurate. It doesn't so much *insert* itself into the control flow as ending the control flow while doing some processing before moving on to the caller/outside block. Presumably because the data of the current block is in an erroneous state and should no longer be trusted.

That still doesn't explain why your code fails to compile.
You expected `CATCH` to have its own special syntax rule when it comes to the semicolon ending a statement.
If it worked the way you expected it would fail one of the important [syntax] rules in Raku, “there should be as few special cases as possible”. Its syntax is not special in any way unlike what you seem to expect.

`CATCH` is just one of many phasers with one important extra bit of functionality, it stops exception propagation down the call stack.

What you seem to be asking for it to instead alter the result of an expression that may throw.

That doesn't seem like a good idea.

```raku
$a + may-die() + $b
```

You want to be able to replace the exception from `may-die` with a value.

```raku
$a + 42 + $b
```

Basically you are asking for the ability to add action‑at‑a‑distance as a feature.

There is also a problem, what if you actually wanted `$a + may‑die` to be replaced instead.

```raku
42 + $b
```

There is no way in your idea for you to specify that.

Even worse, there is a way that could accidently happen. What if `may‑die` started returning a failure instead of exception. Then it would only cause an exception when you tried to use it, for example by adding it to `$a`.

---

If some code throws an exception, the block is in an unrecoverable state and it needs to halt execution. This far, no farther.

If an expression throws an exception, the result of executing the statement it is in, is suspect.
Other statements may rely on that broken statement, so then the whole block is also suspect.

I do not think it would be that good of an idea if it instead allowed the code to continue but with a different result for the current expression. Especially if that value can be far removed from the expression somewhere else inside of the block. (action‑at‑a‑distance)

If you could come up with some code that would be vastly improved with `.resume(value)`, then maybe it could be added.
(I personally think that `leave(value)` would be more useful in such a circumstance.)

I will grant that `.resume(value)` seems like it may be useful for control exceptions.
(Caught with `CONTROL` instead of `CATCH`.)

Comment: Thanks, that's all helpful.  By the way, you said "the only time I would normally use CATCH is when I want to handle several different errors in different ways": I would tend to handle even that case with try, using syntax something like this (sorry about the lack of linebreaks): `do { try {may-fail()} // do given $! { when X::This {…}; when X::That {…}}}`

Comment: @codesections I think you are trying too hard to put a lot of code into a single expression. You are trying to combine a simple thing and a complex thing together and pretend it is still a simple thing. There is a reason you are having to work against the language.

Comment: :-)  It certainly wouldn't be the first time I tried to pack too much in.  But I don't _think_ that's happening here – I think the lack of linebreaks just create that effect.  Here's a gist comparing the code I was suggesting versus what you had in the answer. https://gist.github.com/codesections/df7ac67ba6e88ef907dd3095dc9b8641  As you can see, I was actually suggesting breaking things up into two separate blocks, not combining more.  It's fine if you disagree (TIMTOWTDI!), but I don't feel at all like I'm having to work against the language.

Comment: @codesections `do { try {may-fail()} // do given $! { when X::This {…}; when X::That {…}}}` I've iterated on `trys` and turned it into a `catch` function that distils that idiom and others. Feedback on it (same SO) welcome.